# Timeout Errors && Tests not passing on issues that work locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, npm, tdd

Below I have a set of issues I am currently experiencing. Any help would be great!

[Top of the errors in the Frontend tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj5zp.png)

[Bottom half of the errors in the Frontend tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0i0C.png)

**US-08-** Clicking the cancel reservation button and then clicking "ok" removes the reservation.
-Locally, this works just fine for me and have not had a single issue besides this timeout error, with my experience as of yesterday and today it could very well be related to another test case not working as I have had that happen.

**US-08-** Clicking the cancel reservation button then clicking "cancel" makes no changes.
-Once again locally, this works just fine. This one isn't a timeout error but instead receives a value of "null" and it expected to not be not null? or expected not to be null?  Either way, contrary to the test case title, it doesn't like that it received nothing...

**US-08-** Filling and Submitting the form updates the reservation.
-You may have already guessed it but in case you haven't, timeout error... Works perfectly fine locally, not sure why it's timing out.

**US-06-** Finishing the table removes the reservation from the list.
-This one I have absolutely no idea.. If I mess with anything from the list function or really the reservation.controller & reservation.service file, my computer no longer runs the tests. This also is causing issues in my backend as well because I am not supposed to return data if it's not on the date of the reservation. Not sure AT ALL what to do on this one. What I was going to attempt was to get the other tests passing, than make the tests pass in the backend and turn it in but I am receiving timeout errors

Thank you for your time and solutions!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok so this says Timeout errors. Have you googled something to the effect of "how to solve Timeout errors..." etc?